# How to change default mail address

Tags: android

I have function send mail and it looks like this

```
private void email(String emailTo, String subject, String emailText, ArrayList<DummyItem> lstItemsUpload) {

        // need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ emailTo});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);

        // has to be an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        // convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (int i = 0; i < lstItemsUpload.size(); i++) {
            MyItem myItem = lstItemsUpload.get(i);

            File fileIn = new File(myItem.getPath());
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

If i choose **Email application** in chooser, it's will get *default mail address* and place it in from text box.

Is there any way to put the *from mail address* in the code, so the email application will use the input mail address instead of default mail address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default from mail since the mail client is linked to the user's mail address.